# Unable to compile gRPC java

Tags: grpc-java

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile gRPC for java

The command I am running is gradlew.bat installDist

```
Execution failed for task ':grpc-compiler:compileJava_pluginExecutableJava_pluginCpp'.
> No tool chain is available to build for platform 'x86_64':
    - Tool chain 'visualCpp' (Visual Studio): Could not locate a Visual Studio installation, using the Windows registry and system path.
    - Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC): Could not find C compiler 'gcc' in system path.
    - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang): Could not find C compiler 'clang' in system path.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I have added the Microsoft Visual Studio folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 ) to the path

---

### Update

I have installed gcc and clang, but I still get the above error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and it turend out i skiped a step, change to the example dir and it will work.

```
$ # Clone the repository at the latest release to get the example code:
$ git clone -b v1.8.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java
$ # Navigate to the Java examples:
$ cd grpc-java/examples

**Run a gRPC application**

1. Compile the server    
$ ./gradlew installDist

2. Run the server
$ ./build/install/examples/bin/hello-world-server

3. In another terminal, compile and run the client
$ cd android/helloworld
$ ./gradlew installDebug

Congratulations! You’ve just run a client-server application with gRPC.
```

https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android.html#run-a-grpc-application

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same issue. When you clone the code, the codebase would be latest master. And master code sometimes will be unstable. But in one of the googlegroups the mentioned to checkout v1.7.0 and try, it worked for me.
**git checkout v1.7.0,**